# Blinking string in curses application

Tags: ruby, curses

In the meagre documentation for ruby curses I found this method

```
A_BLINK
Blinking

See ::attrset
```

However, I don't know how to utilize it.

```
win1 = Window.new
win1.addstr.a_blink "Blinking" #=> error
```

Please don't blame me, there is literally no help on google regarding curses. Honestly, at least not for ruby.

Comment: Ruby's `Curses` class is just a wrapper. You can read about the concepts here: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set attributes with [`Curses::Window#attrset`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses/Window.html#method-i-attrset). Here's an example:

```
require "curses"
include Curses

init_screen
begin
  attrs = {
    A_NORMAL =>     'Normal display (no highlight)',
    A_STANDOUT =>   'Best highlighting mode of the terminal.',
    A_UNDERLINE =>  'Underlining',
    A_REVERSE =>    'Reverse video',
    A_BLINK =>      'Blinking',
    A_DIM =>        'Half bright',
    A_BOLD =>       'Extra bright or bold',
    A_PROTECT =>    'Protected mode',
    A_INVIS =>      'Invisible or blank mode',
    A_ALTCHARSET => 'Alternate character set',
  }
  attrs.each { |a, s|
    attrset(a)
    addstr("#{s}\n")
  }
  refresh
  getch
ensure
  close_screen
end
```

Comment: Really good answer, but Blinking doesn't appear to make the string flash, as I thought. Do you think I'll have to create a loop to make a message flash?

Comment: You terminal must support blinking text. Maybe it's just disabled.

Comment: hmm..okay. I'm using the terminal of a fresh installation of Ubuntu. That fact that blinking seems to be disabled by default is a bit annoying. Do you reckon creating a loop would be a good practise then?

Comment: It's like the `<blink>` tag, there might be better options to highlight an important message :)

Comment: Yes, indeed. Always the case with programming :D